# Search in description

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

i have a **opencart 2.3.0.2**
And need make search in description of proudcts too. How to make search in description? because now he just search in name of product.

Comment: You have to modify query in the model-file

Comment: you cah show me query what need modify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the source code - you can do search by product description. All that you need just add to request parameter **filter_description**

[image]